# Apache reverse proxy performance issues

Tags: python, apache, proxy

I have a python webapp that is called through Apache with mod_wsgi on a server behind our firewall, and we've configured a public-facing webserver to act as a reverse proxy to access the webapp.  I've timed access to a reference page returned by the app via the following routes:

- from the machine it is running on (localhost): ~300ms
- from my workstation over VPN directly to the server: ~500ms
- through the reverse proxy: ~2000ms!

One caveat is that the public-facing proxy is using HTTPS, the others are not, but I find it hard to believe that's causing a 1.5s hit.  I'm not really a configuration wizard, so what should I look at to try to figure out what's causing this poor performance?

Comment: Ever figure this out?